# How to filter ListView by using a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TextBox` that searches whatever I have in my `ListView`. I would like to have a `ComboBox` that will allow the user to “Show All”, “Show Match” and “Show Non Match” within the `ListView` depending on search criteria.

```
private void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0, searchStartIndex = selectedIndexPos = 0;
    // Clear previously selected indices
    listView.SelectedIndices.Clear();
    string target = searchTextBox.Text;
    // Search for item with text from the search text box, including subItems, from searchStartIndex, not a prefixSearch
    ListViewItem item = listView.FindItemWithText(target, true, searchStartIndex, false);
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
        *   While the search results in an item found continue searching.                                    *
        *----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    while (item != null)
    {
        count++;
        // Update progressBar
        progressBar.Value = (int)((float)searchStartIndex / listView.VirtualListSize * 100);
        ListView.SelectedIndexCollection indexes = listView.SelectedIndices;
        if (!indexes.Contains(item.Index))
        {
            listView.SelectedIndices.Add(item.Index);
        }
        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
            *   Set the start index to the index after the last found, if valid start index search for next item.*
            *----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        if ((searchStartIndex = item.Index + 1) < listView.VirtualListSize)
        {
            item = listView.FindItemWithText(searchTextBox.Text, true, searchStartIndex, false);
            //  count++;
        }
        else
        {
            item = null;
        }
    }
    if (listView.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Find item with text \"" + searchTextBox.Text + "\" has no result.");
    }
    else
    {
        RefilterListView();
        listView.EnsureVisible(listView.SelectedIndices[0]);
    }
}
```

I would like to have my items in the 'ComboBox' to help filter my 'ListView'. The "Show All" should display all contents of 'ListView' along with item that was searched, the "Show Match" should show only the searched item removing everything else that doesn't match the search and "Show Non Match" should show all of the contents from 'ListView' that doesn't match the searched item.

Comment: What's the problem? What's your question?

Comment: I am not sure how to allow the items in my ComboBox to interact with my search criteria to filter my ListView. How can I filter my ListView by using a ComboBox along with my search TextBox?

Comment: You would probably have a much easier time of it if you used a DataGridView and a DataSOurce.  It is just going to be tedious to search all the rows and columns of a Winforms (??) Listview since it is not a grid

Comment: Do you think RadioButton would be a better option instead of ComboBox? My ListView is virtual so I wanted to keep that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't do it exactly in your case. But I hope I realize it. I mean this is just a solution. You can customize it for your case.

First of all, put a `BindingSource` on your `Form` and bind it to your data:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = data;
```

Then bind your `ListView`(actually `DataGridView`) to the `BindingSource`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

And then define an `enum` like this:

```
public enum Something
{
    ShowMatch = 1,
    ShowNonMatch = 2
}
```

Now, put a `ComboBox` on your `Form` and add your options to it:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("Show All");
comboBox1.Items.Add("ShowMatch");
comboBox1.Items.Add("ShowNonMatch");
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

After that, you can catch the selected item in `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        bindingSource1.Filter = null;
    else
        bindingSource1.Filter = $"Name = '{comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()}'";
}
```

Comment: This will work with a ListView? I am still new to all of this but it looks like you used a DataGridView instead.

Comment: Doesn't matter you used which control to show your data. They always show your data. In this case, you bind all of your data to `bindingSource1` and it lets you filter them. At the same time, your control will be filtered.